# LoadError Unable to autoload constant ( Rails Engine )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-engines

Whenever i hit the endpoints (example: greet ) exposed by rails engine i receive this error.

Error:

```
"LoadError(Unable to autoload constant TestingController, 
expected /local_path/app/controllers/testing_controller.rb to define it): 
/Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/
dependencies.rb:507:in `load_missing_constant'"
```

Engine:

I have an engine with action method `greet` defined as below

```
# type: class
# path: app/controllers/testing_controller.rb
# file name: testing_controller.rb 
module Parent
  module Child
    class TestingController < ApplicationController
      def initialize
        @name = 'BOB'
      end

      def greet
        render json: {'hi': 'hi', 'name': @name}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

routes defined as

```
# type: route
# path: app/config/routes.rb
# file name: routes.rb 
Parent::Child::Engine.routes.draw do
  get 'greet', to: 'testing#greet', as: :greet
end
```

Details:

This engine has been mounted to a gem `ABC` which is then used in the rails app called `Example`. When i hit the `greet` route in the app via 
http://localhost:3000/greet for the first time i receive `LoadError`.

However if i refresh the page it renders the 
json as expected. `{"hi":"hi","name":"BOB"}`.

we have `development.rb` (app/config/env/) has cache and eager load defined as below

```
config.cache_classes = false
config.eager_load = false
```

Ruby: 2.5.1
Rails: 5.2.1

Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message seems to be coming from the expectation that in the root level of the file `testing_controller.rb` has a definition of a `TestingController` class whilst you have that class defined nested within `Parent::Child::` modules.

I guess that if you put your `testing_controller.rb` file in the following path: `app/controllers/parent/child/testing_controller.rb` the error will disappear.

Comment: That did the trick. I wish the error was as clear as you pointed out here. Thank you